# Convert server-generated site to PhoneGap/Cordova app?

Tags: laravel, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

What's the lowest effort way to get a site with server-generated pages (in my case Laravel/PHP) running as a PhoneGap/Cordova app? I'd rather not have to convert the whole thing into a single page app before importing into PhoneGap/Cordova.

Is it possible to use PhoneGap/Cordova as a very thin wrapper and still load each page live from the server? And if so, how exactly please? I don't think we need any native phone APIs.

Reason for the whole thing is my client insists on "having an app" even though obviously our site will work in a mobile web browser and can have an icon on the user's phone.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there an issue with using an iframe in the app?

Comment: not sure, but how would that work?

Comment: `<iframe src="https://example.com/mypage"></iframe>`. What's to stop you from putting that in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for your app to pass Apple App store approval it will have to provide some basic functions and display correctly without an internet connection. This means at a minimum, if you plan to generate content on a server you will probably need the Cordova plugin for network information:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/

I would make sure you are familiar with the Apple Human Interface Guidelines:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/

You will probably also need to bundle any JavaScript. Apple is very picky about apps that download code (this can include JavaScript).

This is a section from the iOS developer Agreement.

> 3.3.2 Except as set forth in the next paragraph, an Application may not download or install 
>   executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and 
>   interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exceptions to the 
>   foregoing are scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework or 
>   JavascriptCore, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the 
>   Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and 
>   advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store.

**The following is my opinion only**

My fear is that if you go at it in a low effort way, best case you will fail app approval. Worst case it will leave users with a poor experience or worse, a poor image of your client. Do it properly and give the app some extra functions that you can't have in a browser alone. I would advise your client of this and see if they would like a proper app that engages their customers and provides them with a great experience.